# JavaScript - regular expression to remove square brackets only at specific places

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Is possible to remove the square brackets only at a specific place in a string? I have the following string:

```
[{
    "text": "Text123",
    "data": [{
        "status": "Pending",
        "validity": "Invalid"
    }],
    "children": [{
        "text": "Text456",
        "data": [{
            "status": "Pending",
            "validity": "Invalid"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I need to remove the square brackets from the data array but keep them everywhere else. The result string should be:

```
[{
    "text": "Text123",
    "data": {
        "status": "Active",
        "validity": "Inactive"
    },
    "children": [{
        "text": "Text456",
        "data": {
            "status": "Pending",
            "validity": "Valid"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with a regular expression?
Thanks!

Comment: Why in the world would you be trying to string mash valid json data? Just read the first element from the `data` array if thats all you're interested in!

Comment: Why do this through regex? it's literally there available to be processed normally as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I find the question a bit weired, but probably you have such a need. Anyway here is the regex:

```
/"data": \[([^\]]*)\]/g
```

then replace by:

```
"data": $1
```

Where \1 is the capturing group

Comment: JavaScript would use `$1` to reference the first capture group. Also, you have a `.` inside it and I don't think it's necessary at all.

Comment: @vlaz yeah it will do without that dot. I didn't see javascript at the first place. Edited.

Comment: Thanks Maverick_Mrt! Yes i know it's a bit weird question - this is a tree structure with unknown depth of nodes. Each inner node can also hold the data array. Parsing each level of the tree and doing data = data[0] seemed like a poor option. The regexp works perfect. Minor changes to make it work: str.replace(/"data":\[([^\]]*)\]/g, "\"data\":$1"). Thanks again for the regex!

Comment: @Koshera - just write a recursive function. You know the simple case - it's solved by a single line of code. You need two to do it recursively. That's two lines versus the _two hours_ it took you to derive find this solution that somebody else wrote for you.

Comment: Yes, somebody else wrote it for me and I am grateful for it. I learned something new today... Someone helped me out and I'm helping other people out in my area of expertise. Isn't that the whole point of stackoverflow? Is this the right approach? Maybe it isn't. Can you convince me that going through the tree with recursion is faster than doing a single regex on a flat string? Which approach uses less resources and CPU cycles? I don't know, but a one liner seems to do the trick pretty well... What exactly in my question pissed you off?

Answer (score 1):

You could just parse the JSON into an object and not have to deal with regex / strings at all.

```
data = data[0]
```

Comment: `use the JSON as JSON` well, you aren't. You are manipulating _objects_ in your example. JSON is text data, represented as a string in JavaScript. To do what you try to with _actual_ JSON, you need to do `JSON.parse(data)` first.

Comment: @vlaz you know what i mean.

Comment: I do and I think it's high time to stop misnaming _objects_ as _JSON_. The two are different and it's a very newbie mistake to call them such. It's akin to confusing Java and JavaScript - it's fine, we could all make this mistake in the beginning but once a certain level of knowledge is reached, namely the difference between the two, then it's time to stop making the mistake.